# Argparse documentation

Tags: documentation, argparse

In the argparse documentation I found the following:

```
ArgumentParser.add_argument(name or flags...[, action][, nargs][, const][, default][, type][, choices][, required][, help][, metavar][, dest]).
```

Why are the parameters written with brackets and a comma inside the brackets? Does it have some meaning?

Why isn't i written like this:

```
ArgumentParser.add_argument(name or flags..., action, nargs, const, default, type, choices, required, help, metavar, dest).
```

Comment: Parameters inside the [,...] are optional.  These parameters can also be given in the keyword format, as you can see in the code examples, like `parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')`.

Comment: I see. But why the commas inside the brackets?

Comment: Where should they put the commas?  It's not an important detail.  The parameters if used will require comma separators.  This is just normal Python syntax.  Nothing special for argparse.

Comment: Another point about these parameters - most have reasonable defaults.  So you only need to provide the ones that are special for your case.  The most common argument specification is `add_argument('foo')` for a positional, and `add_argument('-f', '--foo')` for a flagged argument.

Comment: Actually the signature for `add_argument` should read more like the one for `ArgumentParser`.  All these bracketted arguments are keyword arguments.   All positional arguments (non-keyword) are interpreted as one of the 'names or flags...'.

Comment: What complicates describing `add_argument` is that not all of the parameters make sense, largely depending on the `action` value.  For a `store_true` action, `nargs` is by default 0, and shouldn't be set by the user.  `const` isn't used for the default `store` action.  As a general rule only use the ones you need, and be prepared to correct your code if you get error messages.

Comment: I know the basic syntax. It's just that I assumed that they had some special meaning because they are "inside" the optional arguments. Instead of [op1], [op3], ... ,[optn].

Comment: They just don't want you to write `add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store',,, default='bar',,,help='xxx')`, with extra `,` between skipped parameters.

Comment: The actual signature for `add_argument` is: `def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):`.  That's as generic as it gets.  All those `[,...]` parameters are handled by the `kwargs`.